# Windows Phone WebBrowser Control Not Rotating, Height Not 100%

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, browser

I'm building my first simple Windows Phone app. I'm having some trouble though.

I'm using a WebBrowser control to show a web page that I don't have control over. <strike>For some reason, the control doesn't rotate with the phone. I'm completely at a loss as to why.</strike>

I can't get the height to be 100% of the phone. If I set it to auto, I think it's getting executed as 0.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the XAML for a very simple app that only contains a WebBrowser control. It is full size and rotates. Can you compare with your app and spot what's different? BTW, the only attribute I changed on the  elements was the value of @SupportedOrientations.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    x:Class="WP7WebBrowser.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="PortraitOrLandscape" Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
      <phone:WebBrowser Source="http://www.bing.com"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    </Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Hope that puts you on the right path!

Comment: Thanks. Forgot to set the VerticalAlignment I think. Either that or something about row = 1 or something like that.

Comment: It does not work on windows phone 8 - the WebBrowser gets 0 height even with VerticalAlignment="Stretch"